# not showing appropriate output in c++

Tags: c++

I have written a very simple c++ program on windows. I am using Ming32 compiler for it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    //int k = 55;
   //cout<<k;
   string s = "String";
   cout<< s;
   return 0;
}
```

First I compiled it with having only `int k = 55`;
but when I added the `string` variable it shows no output at all, with the exception of the previous `k` value.

Then, I tried to another int variable where variable's value was different but still it shows the previous `k` value only.
Why is this happening & what is the solution for it ?

Comment: [Can't replicate](https://godbolt.org/z/2xBNuV). Is it perhaps a buffering issue? When, where and how do you check the output?

Comment: which compiler you are using? Is it turbo c++? If yes then you need to add clrscr() function which comes from conio.h header file.

Comment: The program looks fine to me. Probably has something to do with how you compile and run it? If it shows the output of the previous k value if it's supposed to show a string the compilation might have failed and you ran the old program again.

Comment: @SachinMaharjan Read the question again. " i am using Ming32 compiler..."

Comment: Just to be clear, you will not get a line break between `55` and `String`. Thus your output will be `55String`.

Comment: Not an answer, because this is not a definite solution, but some output (like consoles) can be line buffered, so it might help to add newlines (\n) to the output to be a bit more sure about the output.

Comment: It is just showing 55 in output & i am compiling the program on cmd.

Comment: Just to be very sure that source code and binary match, delete the binary and compile again.

Comment: Please report the compile command you use.

Comment: Please show us the complete command you use to build your program. *And* show us how you run your program.